# TCP based decentralised chat app in C

Tags: sockets, tcp, server, client, chat

I need to make TCP based decentralised chat app for local network. By decentralised I mean there is no central server. Each entity on a network should have server/client architecture. When app starts it should check which user is online ( already running the app ). My question is how can i check that? Can i do it by trying to connect via connect() function from socket library? I'm new to programming, especially socket programing, so if it's a dumb question sorry in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely study how other decentralized applications do this. There are lots of techniques.

Each instance of the application should, as part of its server functionality, track the addresses of other instances of the application. Each instance should, as part of its client functionality, keep track of a few instances it can connect to. Prefer instances that have been around for a long time.

The software should include a list of servers that have been running for a long time and are expected to typically be available. You may wish to include a fallback method such DNS, maintained by anyone willing to keep a list of well-known servers offering access through a well-known port. The fallback method can also be IRC or HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay decentralized, you might want to try [multicasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast) or [broadcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting_(networking)) a request packet to all hosts on the network to discover other instances of your chat application.

Something similar has been implemented in Pidgin, named [Bonjour](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Protocol%20Specific%20Questions#BonjourLink-LocalMessaging). It works quite nicely and provides chatting capabilities on a local network. More specifically, it is defined as a [Serverless Messaging part](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html) of [XMPP](http://xmpp.org).

If you are looking for code examples, have a look at one of my projects where I use multicast to discover hosts on the local network that provide a specific service: [Headers](https://github.com/fairlight1337/macdetect/blob/master/utils/include/macdetect-utils/MulticastEndpoint.h) and [implementation](https://github.com/fairlight1337/macdetect/blob/master/utils/src/MulticastEndpoint.cpp).